# Is there a simple way to clone all Starred repos from GitHub?

Tags: github

I am looking to backup all my Starred repositories and I'm searching for a simple a way to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it. Note you will need
[`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq)

```sh
curl https://api.github.com/users/<user>/starred |
  jq -r '.[].html_url' |
  xargs -l git clone
```

If you don't want to use `jq` you can replace with this ugly `awk` line

```sh
awk '/^ {4}"html_url"/&&$0=$4' FS='"' |
```

Comment: I think there is a limit from GitHub API as it stopped cloning after 30 repos.

Comment: @nighthawk24 The results are paginated and the API returns the first 30 by default.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aebb4a0639b0af2cfd88 should do the trick with pagination.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, here is a simple one-liner (change `foo` to your username):

```
USER=foo; curl "https://api.github.com/users/$USER/starred?per_page=1000" | grep -o 'git@[^"]*' | xargs -L1 git clone
```

<sup>Add `-P` parameter for `xargs` to increase speed by setting number of parallel processes (e.g. `-P4` = 4 processes).</sup>

<sup>To raise the GitHub limits, you can authenticate by specifying your API key.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any issues with ruby and can install a few gems, you can give this a shot.

`gem install octokit git parallel`

Then this should do it.

```
ruby -e "require 'octokit'; require 'git'; require 'parallel'; Parallel.each(Octokit.starred('__username__'), :in_processes=>4){|s| Git.clone(s[:html_url], s[:name])}"
```

For readability:

```
require 'octokit'
require 'git'
require 'parallel'

Parallel.each(Octokit.starred('__username__'), :in_processes=>4){|s| Git.clone(s[:html_url], s[:name])}
```

This does seem like overkill though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also fetch the list as suggested, and create a new Repo for thoose projects that you are really interested on backuping. This method will help you update your backups easily.

Create a new repository, public/private, with submodules and clone/pull all toggether. You should see something like [this](https://github.com/DiegoJArg/_synclist_public_).

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
cd <repo>
git submodule add https://github.com/<someone>/<repo1>
git submodule add https://github.com/<someother>/<repo2>
git submodule update --init --recursive
git commit -m "submodules added"
git push
```

Then do

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
# OR
git pull --recurse-submodules
```